# Python - Unable to export sql result to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to export sql query result to excel file using Python.
I queried the DB and able to retrieve the result set.Currently what im facing is like.Not able write the query result to Excel, Here is my Code,

```
def read(db_connect):
   print("Read")
   cursor = db_connect.cursor()
   Expirydate =  date.today() + timedelta(days=90)
   print(Expirydate)
   sql_query = cursor.execute("Select StaffDetails.TypeOfEmployee, StaffDetails.EmploymentType, StaffDetails.EmploymentCategory, StaffDetails.PreferredEmpFname, StaffDetails.PreferredEmpLname, StaffDetails.Location, StaffDetails.Department, StaffDetails.Section, StaffDetails.JobTitle, StaffDetails.ContractorAgencyName, StaffDetails.SupervisorName, StaffDetails.SupervisorEmail, StaffBiodata.WorkpassType, StaffBiodata.WorkpassExpiryDate from StaffDetails INNER JOIN StaffBiodata ON StaffDetails.StaffID =StaffBiodata.StaffID WHERE Department = 'Operations' AND WorkpassExpiryDate < '%s'" % Expirydate)
   allrows = sql_query.fetchall()
   for row in allrows:
      print(f'row = {row}')
      print()
   totalrows = len(allrows)
   print("Total Rows : %d" % totalrows)
   if totalrows > 0:
       try:
           columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
           
           df = pd.DataFrame(allrows)
           writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\CSV\Staffdata.xlsx')
           df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='WorkPassExpiryReport',header=True,index=False)
           writer.save()
           print(title)
           
       except:
           print("Could not write to Excel")
```

When im running this code,its skipping to the except block.Is there anyway to figure out the issue?

---------------------EDIT---------------------
[image]

----------------EDIT 2-------------------

[image]

Thanks,
Teena

Comment: your question is too unclear. are you getting an exception? an error of some sort? do your prints not print what you expect? `print(title)` what is this? you don't have title defined anywhere

Comment: @Nullman print(title) is printing the column names . i am able to retrive row count and resultset of sql query. i forgot to rename title to columns,actually it is print(columns)

Comment: Does it prints Total rows? Your screenshot doesn't show it

Comment: @vovakirdan yes,its totalrows is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3 as sq
db_connect.row_factory = sq.Row # this changes  output
if totalrows > 0:
       try:
           #columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description] i think here is an error
           #it would be better if you write columns manually
           df = pd.DataFrame(allrows, columns = sql_query.keys())
           with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\CSV\Staffdata.xlsx') as writer:
               df.to_excel(writer, 
                           sheet_name='WorkPassExpiryReport',index=False)
           print(columns)
           
       except Exception as e:
           print("Could not write to Excel")
           print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

Try it and send screenshot

Comment: `writer.save()` is outside the `with` statement

Comment: Sorry, my fault

Comment: @vovakirdan, thanks for the quick response.Now the error has gone, but the result is written to single column in excel .Please see the screenshot .and there is no header and my date column is displaying in different way.

Comment: I have updated answer. Try it

Comment: @vovakirdan,Hi im getting these errors File "AutomatedWorkPassExpiryReport.py", line 74, in <module>
    read(db_connect)
  File "AutomatedWorkPassExpiryReport.py", line 50, in read
    db_connect.row_factory = sq.Row
NameError: name 'sq' is not defined     Can i check sq.row is for sqllite3 module .ryt?

Comment: sorry, froget this: `import sqlite3 as sq`.  If there will be an error try `connect.row_factory = sq.Row`

Comment: @vovakirdan , okay, i want to clarify one doubt , im using pyodbc for establishing connection.Is that okay to go with?I have updated my question with connection parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242979/discussion-between-vovakirdan-and-teena).